# Getting Input Type While Running Time

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner of c#.
How can we take type of variable without an Exception parsing to it a variable,while programming is running.We can not know what type of user will enter.

I'm tyring to do this

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Something From Keybord");
        var variable = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (variable.GetType())
        {
            case System.Int32:
                       variable += 1;
                       Console.WriteLine(variable);
                break;
            case System.String:
                        variable +="*";
                        Console.WriteLine(variable);
                        break;
            case System.Double:
                        variable += 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(variable);
                        break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Console.ReadLine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `string` based your input stream as a character.

Your `variable` always will be a `string` *regardless* which type of data input it. That's why your `variable.GetType()` always returns `System.String`. Using *switch statement* would be not logical in that case.

If you want to check your input is a valid `Int32` or `Double`, you can use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to check them they are valid `int` or `double`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Something From Keybord");
var variable = Console.ReadLine();
int i;
double d;
if(Int32.TryParse(variable, out i))
{
    // Your variable is a valid int and it's value assingned to i.
}

if(Double.TryParse(variable, out d))
{
    // Your variable is a valid double and it's value assingned to d.
}
```

Comment: @Archangel I write an example. `TryParse` methods doesn't throw any exceptions. If your `variable` is a valid `int`  or `double`, they return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TryParse-methods for Int, Double etc.

[Int32.TryParse on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Something From Keybord");
        var variable = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (variable.GetType())
        {
            case typeof(int):
                       variable += 1;
                       Console.WriteLine(variable);
                break;
            case typeof(string):
                        variable +="*";
                        Console.WriteLine(variable);
                        break;
            case typeof(double):
                        variable += 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(variable);
                        break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```